# How do I write below code using dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, list, dictionary, optimization, dictionary-comprehension

Need  help to optimize below python code using dictionary comprehension. How can  modify my code in such a way that using python special features

````
        container_status = {}
        active=[]
        inactive=[]
        not_found=[]
        if containers:
            for container in containers:
                inspect_dict = cli.inspect_container(container)
                state = inspect_dict['State']
                is_running = state['Status'] == 'running'
                if is_running:
                    active.append(container)
                else:
                    inactive.append(container)        
            container_status= {'active':active,'inactive':inactive,'not_found':not_found }     
            print(container_status)```
````

Comment: @pierre-b Could you please help me in the optimization

Comment: The first 3 lines of the` for loop` don't depend upon container.  Why are they set in the for loop?  Then all containers would be either active or inactive.

Comment: Thanks, @DarrylG for notifying the mistake now it is cleared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
container_status = {}
active=[]
inactive=[]
not_found=[]
inspect_dict = cli.inspect_container('festive_bell')
if containers:              
    ls_to_append = active if inspect_dict['State']['Status'] == 'running' else inactive
    for container in containers:
        ls_to_append.append(container)
    container_status= {'active':active,'inactive':inactive,'not_found':not_found }     
    print(container_status)
```

Note that each time that it's run it will show all the containers as active or inactive since it's depends on `cli.inspect_container('festive_bell')` results all of them have the same results

Comment: Issues is `active.append(container)` returns None since append is in-place.

Comment: It's supposed to return None but still to assign the container into the expected list

Comment: I see you're using it as a side effect.  But, confusing since [Is it Pythonic to use list comprehensions for just side effects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects)

Comment: Understood, I edit the code to do the same with one more line.

Comment: There is no need to run over the list since the value is the same to all containers so you can just do it by an if statement

Comment: You want `active.append(container)` rather than `active.extend(container)` otherwise if containers are lists, active will just be all the container lists merged together.

Comment: On your code when you run on each container for containers and append the container to the active/inactive lists it's the same as active/inactive.extend(containers) since it's chacking if inspect_dict['State']['Status'] is the same to all of them

Comment: To change the extend to append?